# why segmentation fault in c and how to make it work?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

```
#include "stdio.h"

void save(char* savefile, char ch);

int main()
{
        char* savefile = {0};
        char ch;
        scanf("%c", &ch);
        printf("%s\n", savefile);

        return 0;
}

void save(char* savefile, char ch)
{
        savefile[strlen(savefile)] = ch;
}
```

so i was trying to make a program that saves what i typed.
And i can't get why it isn't working.
i'm guessing that changing savefile is the messy part.

Comment: where are you calling function `save()`? `printf("%s\n", savefile);` will cause undefined behaviour , since `savefile` its not initialized with proper value, its just `NULL`

Comment: Now is the perfect time to pick up an introductory book on the C language and start reading.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is that `savefile` is a pointer initialized to NULL so when you call `printf("%s\n", savefile);` you pass a NULL pointer. Then `printf` dereferences the NULL pointer and you get a crash.

Instead you want `savefile` to be an array of chars so that it can hold a C-style string.

Your code is kind of strange as you never call the function `save`. Maybe you want something like:

```
#define MAX_LEN 32

int main()
{
        char savefile[MAX_LEN + 1] = {0};   // Make savefile an array of
                                            // (MAX_LEN + 1) chars. All 
                                            // initialized to zero
        char ch;
        scanf("%c", &ch);
        save(savefile, ch);                 // Call the function
        printf("%s\n", savefile);

        return 0;
}

void save(char* savefile, char ch)
{
    size_t len = strlen(savefile);
    if (len < MAX_LEN )
    {
        savefile[len] = ch;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Because your `char` array is NULL

You called `printf` with a char array, whose value is `NULL`, leading to undefined behavior and segmentation fault. First, give `savefile` some valid value, then try again, it should work.

Comment: There is no `char` array in the shown code. Also `save` is not called at all and hence cannot cause the segmentation fault` in the line you show. Also normally `NULL` is only used for the `NULL` pointer constant. For strings it would be better to call it "null" or "nul".

Comment: Thanks, @Gerhardh. I just missed that out.